# ps warns me about  bad syntax with "aux" options

Tags: linux, ps

When I attempt to run the command `ps` with the flags/switches/options `aux` I get the following message. If I run the command without grep, no message is displayed. What am I doing wrong?

```
ps -aux | grep 'skype'
Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? 
See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html
```

Comment: Wait, did you even read the link you posted? It answers your question.

Comment: @The Electric Muffin - I did however don't understand when it states 'x' refers to a specific user.

Comment: @The Electric Muffin - Does it mean I can run the command ps -aux{username}?

Comment: The `-u username` switch selects processes belonging to _username_, so `ps -upeanuts` would select every process belonging to the user peanuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should (and did for me) display that warning whether or not it's piped to grep. The real issue is the `-aux` switch. The manpage says:

> Note that "ps -aux" is distinct from "ps aux". The POSIX and UNIX
>   standards require that "ps -aux" print all processes owned by a user
>   named "x", as well as printing all processes that would be selected by
>   the -a option. If the user named "x" does not exist, this ps may
>   interpret the command as "ps aux" instead and print a warning."

Answer (score 4):

BSD options to `ps` do not take a dash.

```
ps aux
```

Comment: I understand that however what is the difference between `ps -aux` and `ps aux`

Comment: One is incorrect and the other is correct.

Comment: But why is that? Does `x` refer to the username of a user?

Comment: `x` is a BSD-style option.

Comment: Sorry for being a n00b but what does that mean?

Comment: It means that it is an option that was taken from the BSD version of `ps`.

Comment: Great. Thanks because the guide I was reading seem to infer `x` as a username i.e.....plus all processes owned by a user named "x"